# Has the Control Key + Rotation snapping increment been changed or dropped?

Tags: modeling, snapping

Many sources describe holding the Control key down while rotating to control rotation by 5 degrees increments. I cannot get this keyboard shortcut to work in Blender v2.75. The increment button on the snapping menu does work, but the keyboard shortcut does not seem to work for me.

Comment: I'm running 2.75a on Windows 7. Can confirm that holding Ctrl while rotating does work as described on my system.

Comment: Do you turn off snapping while making `Ctrl` to work ?

Comment: Mr Zak I leave the snap to vertex on while I use the ctrl+R to rotate in Object Mode. However, I have tested it by turning snap off and the results are the same.

Comment: Does it work if you *turn off* snap, but still select *Increment* option for it (after turning it off) ?

Comment: I have learned through testing that when the Snap TYPE is set to increment and Snap is EITHER ON or OFF, the ctrl+R will rotate the selected object by an increment of 5 Degrees. This requirement of having the Snap TYPE in only one of the available settings was not readily apparent from the many tutorials I watched on this topic of Rotation. Thanks to all who commented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you choose to [rotate with 5 degrees precision](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/transform/control/precision/introduction.html#rotation) (or another transform operation), you should hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while performing transform operation; if holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> [rotation will happen by 1 degree](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/transform/control/precision/introduction.html#precision-snapping). **Snap during transform** should be turned off, but its option *Increment* should be checked:

[image]

Transforming without precision will be done in case of other snapping option selected.

If you turn on **Snap during transform**, you can perform transforms with precisions *without* holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:

[image]

You may want to read about [performing transforms with precision in manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/transform/control/precision/introduction.html).

Comment: Mr Zak, I read the Blender Reference Article related to Precision during the transform and it does not give any indication that the "Increment" option in the Snap Menu is a prerequisite for the use of the ctrl as a Hotkey. Here is an opportunity for the developers to do an enhancement or update the Reference Manual, or both. I will explore the idea of requesting the enhancement.

Comment: The links show me a 404

Comment: @JanDvorak thanks, manual changed their links since then.

Comment: Is this different AGAIN in blender 2.9?  Ctrl+Alt+DoubleBuckyCokebottle+Meta+Function + mouse drag?

Comment: @Warren you can search for current shortcuts in user prefs > keymap > enter name of operator / shortcut depending on filter. Or you can ask new question with explanation of your problem. 2.9 shouldn't be drastically different here, but devs indeed really like changing shortcuts all over (even if just changing e.g X to Y with both being free).

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>ctrl + shift + tab</kbd> and switch snapping to `increment`

Comment: Thank you! I was looking all over for what I accidentally turned on.